# How can you make this equation solvable

Tags: mathematics

How can you make this equation right?

> 5+4+5=550

**Note**

- You can not change the equation, of course
- You only get to put **ONE LINE** through anywhere on the equation

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before, but I think yours has a typo. 544+5 = 549, not 550.

Comment: @Kingrames Or 5+5+5=550, giving 545+5=550.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Those "clues" seem to be necessary parts of the question - please do not hide anything behind spoilers that is necessary to solve the puzzle.

Comment: I dont have a typo in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what solvable means, but is it:

> $5+4+5\ne550$

Answer (score 6):

Using one line we can make an equality that is valid:

> $544+5=550$
>  Which is valid in base $9$:
>  $(5\times9^2+4\times9^1+4\times9^0)+(5\times9^0)=(5\times9^2+5\times9^1+0\times9^0)$
>  $(405+36+4)+(5)=(405+45+0)$
>  $445+5=450$
>  $450=450$